# Which European (EASA, EU) regulation corresponds to US FAR 91.13 on "careless or reckless" operation of aircraft?

Tags: easa-regulations

The US has [14 CFR 91.13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.13) about "careless or reckless" operation of aircraft, as a sort of catch-all for activities which are not explicitly prohibited by the regulations but which are still a bad idea and risks to, or actually, puts others in danger:

> § 91.13 Careless or reckless operation.
>
> (a) Aircraft operations for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.
>
> (b) Aircraft operations other than for the purpose of air navigation. No person may operate an aircraft, other than for the purpose of air navigation, on any part of the surface of an airport used by aircraft for air commerce (including areas used by those aircraft for receiving or discharging persons or cargo), in a careless or reckless manner so as to endanger the life or property of another.

I have a hard time imagining that Europe doesn't have a similar statute, but I can't seem to find anything looking through Part-FCL or my local regulations.

**What is the EASA or EU regulation corresponding to the US FAR 91.13?**

Comment: A good question. Keep in mind every EASA member country has its on variation on aviation regs, but they should all be roughly similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered by [SERA.3101](https://www.caa.co.uk/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=4294975756) (Page 19) for the UK:

> **SERA.3101 Negligent or Reckless Operation of Aircraft**
>   An aircraft shall not be operated in a negligent or reckless manner so as to endanger life or property of others.